# AngularJS - Dynamic forms inside arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

So, I have here the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Essentially, I have a dynamic array of people like so:

```
  $scope.users = [
    {
      name: 'James',
      data: []
    },
    {
      name: 'Bob',
      data: []
    },
    {
      name: 'Walter',
      data: []
    }
  ];
```

I have forms that those people need to fill out. Those come in small, simple directives. James has to fill both directive's form, Bob has to fill out one, and Walter has fill out one (but it's the one Bob didn't fill out).

Those forms come in object form like `$scope.basicDataFormData` and `$scope.styleRequestFormData` and at the main level, we attach it like so:

```
  $scope.data = {
    basic_data: $scope.basicDataFormData,
    style_request: $scope.styleRequestFormData
  }
```

At `$scope.menu.currentIndex`, we govern what user page to show and it is either reset to `0` or increases when you hit `Next user`.

So, each user's `data` object, from `$scope.users`, is based on what the current `$scope.data` is, right? Wrong.

https://plnkr.co/edit/zGVPViVTkepGB1ZO3PbU?p=preview

As you can see, it doesn't work *exactly* how it's suppose to. From the example, the form data gets copied over to the next one. And now, both user 1 and user 2 are getting the same exact data when `menu.currentIndex` is obviously only dictating `1` when `next user` gets pressed.

Can someone help me out here?

The way it's suppose to work is that all of those forms should only be written to the current user's `data` object that `menu.currentIndex` is on. That way, each form is persistant to that user's form view. James should have two objects inside his data while Bob and Walter with only 1.

Comment: is this fixed or something? i cant reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the initialize function you are assigning one object to another like so:

```
function initialize() {
    $scope.data.basic_data = $scope.basicDataFormData;
    $scope.users[$scope.menu.currentIndex].data = $scope.data;
}
```

This is not correct, because it just points them to the same place in memory. Instead, you want to clone the object. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy.

The function should be:

```
function initialize() {
    $scope.data.basic_data = angular.copy($scope.basicDataFormData);
    $scope.users[$scope.menu.currentIndex].data = angular.copy($scope.data);
}
```

Comment: I'd rather not mix jQuery with Angular at all and looking to find a solution in Angular.

Comment: Okay, well then use angular.copy https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: Either way, the point is you want to manually copy the object onto the other object instead of assigning it with the = operator

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: np, if that solves your problem, do you mind upvoting my answer?

Comment: I'm a bit confused where `angular.copy()` should go. Can you help me edit the plnkr and show me?

Comment: Try angular.copy in this way: `$scope.data.basic_data = angular.copy($scope.basicDataFormData); `

Comment: I finally got it here, using your answer as a base: https://plnkr.co/edit/zGVPViVTkepGB1ZO3PbU?p=preview